# Passenger + Apache + Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, gcloud

After running

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I Have

```
[Thu Dec 04 15:30:37 2014] [warn] module passenger_module is already loaded, skipping
Syntax error on line 274 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'PassengerDefaultRuby', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in          the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

In the end of apache.conf i have: ( this lines i got after passenger-install-apache2-module)

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/r$
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
 PassengerRoot /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gem$
 PassengerDefaultRuby /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.$
</IfModule>
```

In /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.rackexample.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ruslan/blog/public
    <Directory /home/ruslan/blog/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
        #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite i have the same :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.rackexample.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ruslan/blog/public
    <Directory /home/ruslan/blog/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
        #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, if i open uri i have :

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at 146.148.7.236 Port 80

What can be a problem? (I am using Debian on Google Developers Console if it is important)

I also noticed same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103946/vps-apache-config-invalid-command-passengerdefaultruby-after-adding-latest-p), but i can't find difference.

**UPD:**
I deleted line in the end of apache.conf, which contains

```
LoadModule passenger_module
```

And now i have this error:

```
ruslan@olga-blog:~$ sudo service apache2 restart
Syntax error on line 273 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'PassengerDefaultRuby', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

So i see in the end of apache log with tail -f -n 100 /var/log/apache2/error.log ( Fir 05 - it is today, so it is latest logs) :

```
[Fri Dec 05 03:00:07 2014] [error] [client 180.153.195.33] Premature end of script headers:
[Fri Dec 05 03:20:20 2014] [error] [client 76.14.162.37] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /tmUnblock.cgi
App 10140 stderr: [ 2014-12-05 03:46:21.5488 10221/0x00000000e1d2f0(Worker 1) utils.rb:84 ]: *** Exception RuntimeError in Rack application object (Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`) (process 10221, thread 0x00000000e1d2f0(Worker 1)):
App 10140 stderr: from /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:462:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
App 10140 stderr: from /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:195:in `env_config'
App 10140 stderr: from /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
App 10140 stderr: from /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
App 10140 stderr: from /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
App 10140 stderr: from /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
App 10140 stderr: from /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
App 10140 stderr: from /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:455:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
[Fri Dec 05 03:46:21 2014] [error] [client 180.153.196.169] Premature end of script headers:
App 10140 stderr: [ 2014-12-05 04:26:21.9010 10221/0x00000000e1d2f0(Worker 1) utils.rb:84 ]: *** Exception RuntimeError in Rack application object (Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`) (process 10221, thread 0x00000000e1d2f0(Worker 1)):
App 10140 stderr: from /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:462:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
App 10140 stderr: from /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:195:in `env_config'
App 10140 stderr: from /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
App 10140 stderr: from /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
App 10140 stderr: from /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
App 10140 stderr: from /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
App 10140 stderr: from /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
App 10140 stderr: from /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:455:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
[Fri Dec 05 04:26:21 2014] [error] [client 171.13.14.23] Premature end of script headers:
```

**UPD2:**
I added secret key to my_app/config/secrets.yml

Remove log file and create it

```
sudo rm -rf /var/log/apache2/error.log
sudo touch /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Restart Apache and have this error again:

```
ruslan@olga-blog:~/blog$ sudo service apache2 restart
Syntax error on line 273 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'PassengerDefaultRuby', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

And log are empty with

```
tail -f -n 100 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

**UPD3:**
TRYING:
sudo aptitude purge libapache2-mod-passenger
sudo apt-get install rubygems build-essential apache2-prefork-dev libapr1-dev libssl-dev zlib1g-dev
sudo gem install passenger
passenger-install-apache2-module
Paste the output to the end of apache2.conf ( previous lines about passenger above deleted)

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.53/buildout/apache2/mod$
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.53
     PassengerDefaultRuby /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/ruby
   </IfModule>
```

Restarted apache again , and have apache message

```
It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

Why?

**UPD4**

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf
```

look empty , why?

**UPD5:**

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger
```

remove LoadModule line from apache.conf
restart apache
and still have

```
ruslan@olga-blog:~/blog$ sudo service apache2 restart

Syntax error on line 273 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'PassengerDefaultRuby', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

**UPD6:** Command sudo passenger-status shows:

```
Version : 4.0.53
Date    : Fri Dec 05 10:34:32 +0000 2014
Instance: 1021
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
Processes     : 0
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
ruslan@olga-blog:~$ apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES|grep -i passenger
-bash: apachectl: command not found
ruslan@olga-blog:~$ apachectl configtest
-bash: apachectl: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reinstall all again (**passenger only through rubygems**) and it works fine.
So, it is my 'how to install passenger + apache + ruby':

1. Install apache:

   sudo apt-get install apache2
2. Install rvm

   \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
3. Install passenger through rubygems:

   gem install passenger
4. Run the Phusion Passenger installer

   passenger-install-apache2-module
5. Create your rack app like this

   [in passenger doc example](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_tutorial_example_writing_and_deploying_a_hello_world_rack_application)
6. Add VirtualHost block to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/rack_app
7. Create /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.conf with PassengerRoot,
   PassengerDefaultRuby
8. Create /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.load with LoadModule
   block

   sudo a2ensite rack_app
   sudo a2enmod passenger
   sudo service apache2 restart

Have fun!

For more details see comments in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, and [Passenger Apache Docs](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_tutorial_example_writing_and_deploying_a_hello_world_rack_application)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a guess at this one, I think the problem might be here:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/r$
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
    PassengerRoot /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gem$
    PassengerDefaultRuby /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.$
</IfModule>
```

In my `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` I have:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /Users/martin/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.21/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /Users/martin/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.21
PassengerDefaultRuby /Users/martin/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby
```

The `$` on your lines will either be because your terminal window isn't wide enough so it's letting you know that the text has been truncated (so you might have the correct settings but just not copied them correctly - resize terminal window or scroll right to check) or it's been like this when you've ran the apache passenger installer and went to copy the truncated text and not the full lines, I recommend re-running the apache mod installer and making sure you capture the output correctly and try that.

Hopefully that's the case and then it's an easy fix.

**Update**

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/martin/Desktop/app_name/public"
<Directory "/Users/martin/Desktop/app_name/public">
    RailsEnv development
    Options -MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

You might need to use `production` instead of development if that's the case, but I don't see the `RailsEnv` option anywhere in the config that you posted but I think your problem is going to be something silly like that where you are only missing one or two things.

Some commands that might help to debug:

```
apachectl configtest
cat /var/log/apache2/error_log

sudo passenger-status
apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES|grep -i passenger
```

Comment: Thanks for response! No, $ - is truncated by nano , i updated my answer(see UPD3)

Comment: ah, that pretty much renders my answer useless then, I'll post my settings for the directory and see if that helps.